# HTML element that contains no formatting

Tags: html, formatting, tags

I'm constantly modifying some text on a web page with JavaScript. I want the
text to be in-line with other elements, like texts, inputs, etc. What HTML element should I use? Both `<div>` and `<p>` create new-lines and other things. `<b>` kind of does what I want, but it bolds all the text. What's the correct alternative?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [`<span>` tag](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/span) is the in-line equivalent of `<div>`.

Answer (score 5):

`<span>`

you could also apply a display:inline style to a `<div>` and get similar results

Answer (score 5):

You can apply a [`float`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html), [`inline`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#inline) or [`inline-block`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#inlineblock) to elements to get them to show up next to other elements. You can also use `span`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `font-weight` CSS property to make the `<b>` element not bold and to keep everything inline:

```css
.format {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<b class="format">I am some text</b>
```